# Cauchy Problem as Continuous Operator between Normed Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Let $\lambda \colon [0, T] \times (0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ as well as some reasonable $f \colon (0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ and consider the following Cauchy boundary value problem:
$$\partial_t u(t, x) = \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2(t, x) x^2 \partial_x^2 u(t,x),\quad u(0, \cdot) = f.$$

I am interested in identifying the boundary value problem as a continuous operator between normed spaces.
Are there normed spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that it is safe to take $\lambda$ from $X$ and find the corresponding solution $u_\lambda$ to be existing in $Y$, and that all in a way that makes $$X  
\to Y, \quad \lambda \mapsto u_\lambda$$ continuous?

Comment: The subject you need to look at is "functional analysis", and in particular, Sobelev spaces.